# How can I study for a math exam to maximize my ability to solve problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

So I have a linear algebra final in a little over a week. I have already started to study, this consists of going through notes and rewriting the important definitions, proofs, theorems, etc. After I have worked my way through all the chapters we were taught I will practice problems from previous exams and in homework sections in our class notes.

However, whenever I study for exams like this I find that I constantly have to look back at examples to start solving the problem. I can generally continue the problem once seeing how it is started, but I struggle to come up with methods of solving on my own. For this course's midterm, I felt confident and knew my stuff but blanked on a couple of problems which really brought down my mark.

So what should I be doing in order to maximize my likelihood of success? Or rather, is there a unique that math (or linear algebra) should be studied to benefit the student?

Comment: what's your next exam on?

Comment: My suggestion is to carefully pore over the proofs of the standard theorems and see the *methods* that are used to prove them. Then write them out in your own words (with minimal reference to the original proof) so that they are mathematically equivalent, but you understand exactly what you have written.

Comment: @SakethMalyala It is on chapters such as Mathematical Induction, Complex Numbers, Vectors and Planes, Matrices and Determinants, and Linear Transformations and Eigenvectors/values

Comment: @Math1000 Yeah, that is kind of what I have started to do, I am rewriting most of the stuff from the class notes in simplistic words so that I can easily reread it. My problems don't come so much with proofs, I am having more difficulty with, for example, proving linear independence. I know how it works and once I figure out the starting components I have no trouble, it is merely getting over the initial hurdle that I am struggling with.

Comment: Linear independence is a relatively simple definition. A finite set of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in V$ is *linearly independent* if and only if the equation $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$, where $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in F$ (the field the vector space is over) has only the trivial solution $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$. So you have to start with the equation and then show that the scalars must all be zero for it to hold (to prove that a given set of vectors is linearly independent).